# Deploy a magento2 existing project in a virtual machine with ubuntu to be able to run in localhost

Tags: magento2, import, ubuntu

I have an existing Magento2 project hosted on a server, and now I want to import it to my virtual machine. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1-Created a virtual machine and installed Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

2-Copied the entire Magento project folder (which includes folders like app, bin, dev, generated, vendor, and other files) to the path /var/www/html/vhosts/magento/.

3-Created a database and imported the data from the existing project.

4-Updated the values in the core_config_data table to reflect the new URL as "http://localhost/".

5-Modified the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file to point to the path of the Magento project.

Before updating the core_config_data table, when I accessed the virtual machine, I was redirected to a web page that displayed the correct login page for my project (not the index.html page). However, after making the changes in the table to use "localhost" as the URL, I am now seeing a different page (the index.html page) instead of the login page.

I would appreciate if someone could provide guidance on the necessary steps to properly deploy the project on localhost after installing all the required components and making the necessary file modifications. I would like to be able to make changes to the code and see them reflected when accessing the project locally.